# Firebase keeps sending me insecurity warnings for my real time database even though my rules prevent root level access

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a public website that I share with a few of my colleagues and I am using firebase hosting and a real-time database to store my data. Below you will see my security rules. Firebase keeps sending me warning emails that my database has public access. I contacted their support and they recommended that I go further through the documentation and avoid root access to my data nodes. I did as recommended, but I am still getting the warning emails with the same message for insecure
[rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OAij.jpg).

My desired behavior is to have the **Posts node be read publicly**

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

```
{
  "rules": 
  {
    ".read": false,
    ".write" :false,
    "data":
    {
        "Posts":
        {
          ".read":true,
          ".write":false
        }
    },
    "users":
    {
      "data":
        {
          "Posts":
            {
              ".read":"auth != null",
              ".write":"auth != null"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The current security rules allow any authenticated user to read/write the entire `users/data/Posts` node. Is that intended?

Comment: These rules should not be triggering alerts. Are you sure the emails you receive are from this project, and about its realtime database? If so, can you edit your question to include the exact message you get?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen

My apologies for the late reply. Yes, the email redirects me to these rules.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes that is my intended behavior. I feel like I am missing something. `users/data/Posts` should have full public read rights, only read to be public. Authenticated users will have full access to the post node because they will be editing that specific node just like any other database table. Only authenticated users should be able to do so. Other than those rules, everything else should be blocked.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I couldn't edit my previous comment, but I have included a link that shows the exact warning message I get. I can't include images in my questions as I am not allowed to do that yet.

Comment: I double checked with out engineering team, and these rules should indeed not trigger the alert. It may take a day of two before the alerts stop coming though. Has it been that long since you changed the rules?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have not been forwarded any warning email from my executives since May 20th. I believe the issue is resolved. Thank you very much for your time.